# Split String of Accel Values and save what is split - Java

Tags: java, string, split, save

I want to split a string with Accelerometer values into each axis (x,y,z). However, the data is constantly changing so there is no set value for `split()` to search through. I need it to search through the string, take out the axes to separate strings, then save them.

Here's my code, which just saves the whole string to a file:

```
try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("/sdcard/YS Data/Accelerometer.html",
                            true)));
            writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + text
                    + "</h3><br>");
            writer.flush();


            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();


        }
```

I've tried

```
String[] array = writer.split("y");
```

to get from the y value on, but it says I have to add a cast, which when I add

```
((String) writer).split("x");
```

gives me an error. (Cannot cast from PrintWriter to String)

Basically, because I know there is and x,y and z in the string, I was thinking if first I take all of the data in the text string (that contains all sensor data) from x on and put it in a new string, then split that string from y on into another string, then from that split z off to another string. That way I'd have three strings, one for x, y and z.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this :    

                String axis="x=-0.125 y=0.9375 z=0.375";
                String[] tempArr=axis.split(" ");
                ArrayList arr=new ArrayList<String>();
                for(String a:tempArr){
                    arr.add(a.split("=")[1].trim());
                }
                System.out.println(arr);
```

this will sperate the all the values of x,y&z

Comment: Nothing happens. the rest of the code executes as normal. the data still saves to the file with no change to data. Thanks for answer though. I'm trying to mess with it to get it to work. Actually, I just got it partially working. Thanks a million!!! I hould be able to finish it from here :D

Answer (score 0):

> I know there is and x,y and z in the string, I was thinking if first
>   I take all of the data in the text string (that contains all sensor
>   data) from x on and put it in a new string, then split that string
>   from y on into another string, then from that split z off to another
>   string. That way I'd have three strings, one for x, y and z.

What you are saying is corrent . You have to do like this only.

Comment: Thanks. I know what i need, I just don't know how to do it, as the seemingly traditional way of splitting a string is not working for me, do you know any alternative that might work in my situation?

Comment: @Gurfuffle For precision , Can you give one example that type of data that is going to  be split ?

Comment: Sure - the data coming in would look like this: 
x=-0.125 y=0.9375 z=0.375 - all of it being one string